# Firebase used \n show squrebox not display new line

Tags: android, firebase

In Firebse i used \n to display new line but it not show proper text it show 
    squre box in output.

```
Questoin:"A: せんせいは（　）ですか。\n B: はい、にほんじんです。"

In Dialog text first line :"A: せんせいはにほんじんですか。\n B: はい、にほんじんです。"



in Dialog Text English: "A: Is the teacher Japaense?\n B: Yes, she is Japanese."
```

Hear is firbase database image [image]

[image]

Comment: How are you setting the text in textView?

Comment: looks like you have some extra char there:

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually providing the text, You should do it like below instead of giving `\n`

Questoin:

```
    "A: せんせいは（　）ですか。
     B: はい、にほんじんです。"
```

In Dialog text first line :

```
    "A: せんせいはにほんじんですか。
     B: はい、にほんじんです。"
```

in Dialog Text English:

```
    "A: Is the teacher Japaense?
     B: Yes, she is Japanese."
```

Comment: Thanks for response derek  but its not working when i  add data as per suggestion on firebase database mannually it show on single line and space  second sentance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace string like below.

```
label.text = yourString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "\n")
```